# Evaluate pipe in angular 2

Tags: angular

Is there a pipe in angular2 that takes a function (and maybe some arguments) , evaluates the function and outputs the result of the evaluation?

You would use it like this :

```
{{ expensiveFunction | evaluate }}
```

The advantage of this over

```
{{ expensiveFunction() }}
```

would be that the expensive function is not repeatedly evaluated. If such a pipe does not exists (I was not able to find it), is there a reason for it? Would it be a bad idea to make such a pipe?

Comment: Angular2 comes with a very limited built-in pipes such as DatePipe, UpperCasePipe, LowerCasePipe, CurrencyPipe, and PercentPipe. You going to have to create your own custom pipe to achieve what you need.

Comment: Why would you need to have a pipe like this? Why would you choosing when to evaluate the expression increase performance?

Comment: Imagine that the function takes a wile to calculate, if you were to use the usual approach , i.e. {{ myFunction() }} , the function gets called very often. In contrast {{ myfunction | evaluate }} would only calculate the function once every time the function changes.